# How can I change the display of long file names in Windows Explorer to 1 - 2 lines?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

When you have files (or folders) with long names, in "large icons" mode, Windows Explorer will display the file names over four lines, as shown in the image below:

[image]

However, I want to limit them to only 1 - 2 lines, because the default 4 lines of file names are obstacle in the browsing of folders plenty of files with long names. Here's the photoshopped mockup of what I want:

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this? I'm using Windows 11 Home 22H2 build 22621.963.

P.S.
I would like to change the way file names are displayed in "large icons" mode (not other view modes) with a non-destructive method (i.e., not changing the actual file names). Is there any registry entry, or some hacks, to change how many characters to be displayed in file names? If this is impossible, I'll try alternate file manager.

Comment: I just hover over the name and I can see it.  I would rather the display be organized.

Comment: Do you know what changes you made to Windows 11?  Can you reverse the changes?   What you want is default behavior.

Comment: We can't modify Explorer. If the way it works is bothering you, use an alternate File Manager.

Comment: Shorten the filenames., e.g., convert to 8.3 format: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227144/convert-long-filename-to-short-filename-8-3-using-cmd-exe

Answer (score 0):

1. For files shown on the *Desktop*, make **shortcuts** to each of the polysyllabically-named files, and *rename the shortcuts*. *N.B.:* renaming the file itself might have undesired effects. There are tools to do so as a batch, such as the free third-party tool [Bull Rename Utility](https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/), or [it can be done in the CMD prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227144/convert-long-filename-to-short-filename-8-3-using-cmd-exe).
2. For display in Windows Explorer, try different viewing modes. For example:

   a. Press <kbd>Ctr</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> for the *Extra large icons* view, which has more room under the icons so that the filename might fit on two or even one line.

   b. Press <kbd>Ctr</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> for the *Details* view, which has resizable columns, so you can restrict the lenght of the displayed filename.